# Installing Skype4Py on Windows

Tags: python, skype4py

I'm trying to install Skype4Py on windows, but it just keeps throwing this error at me and I have no idea how to solve it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\Temp\Programming\Skype4Py-1.0.34\setup.py", line 152, in <module>
    cmdclass=commands)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 140, in setup
    raise SystemExit, gen_usage(dist.script_name) + "\nerror: %s" % msg
SystemExit: usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands``
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe this helps: how to use virtualenv on Windows http://www.tylerbutler.com/2012/05/how-to-install-python-pip-and-virtualenv-on-windows-with-powershell/ to install Python packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What command are you using for the installation?

Do you have `install` option in it?

Command for installation should look like this:

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: I'm really new to this sorry, but where do I put that?

Comment: This is the command to install the Skype4Py packet. I assume you have downloaded the source code and extracted it. Then you must open Windows CMD tool and navigate to folder where source code that you downloaded is. In that folder find file names setup.py and run the command that I posted above. If you weren't using CMD method, then can you please specify how you got the output before? Or if you need additional help with CMD tool, I'm happy yo help

Comment: The way I was doing it was going to the setup.py file and opening it with python and then running it with the shell.  I'll try out your method, thanks for the help.